# Set retry logic for segments in AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, streaming, avplayer, playback

**Is there any possibility of setting a retry logic for segments in AVPlayer?**

I want AVPlayer to retry for as long as it has a buffer available when receiving a 404 for a segment. Unfortunately, I tried to find a way to set it in the code with no success.

I found that when AVPlayer gets these error codes, it exec the recovery below:

- 401, 403, 404: Retry
- 410, 500, 502, 503, 504: Switch other variants.

From what I understand, the segment should retry automatically. If so, what's the logic behind it? How many times will AVPlayer try again? I couldn't find it. Is it known at all?